# 'Clock' app does not show up in Running Applications

Tags: alarm, clock, application-manager

My Nexus S comes with a default clock application where I can set an alarm. When I set an alarm then I see a little clock in my status bar.

If I go to 'Manage Applications' or 'Running Services', I would expect to see Clock there, but I don't?

If I go to 'All' from 'Manage Applications', then I do see the Clock app, and I can Force Quit it, however the clock in the status bar still appears.

Why doesn't the default Clock application ever appear in Running Applications or Services?

Comment: Probably because it's part of the system and is never supposed to stop running?

Comment: If it's part of the system, can developers access this Clock app? For instance I am creating an alarm application, should it be possible to hookup the alarms from my application to the system Clock app?

Comment: That I don't know. Any dev questions should be asked on [SO].

Comment: I don't see it either (also a Nexus S).  However, while I had the "Running" tab open, I hit the menu button and chose "Show Cached Processes"; that caused the Clock app to appear in the list.  I don't honestly know what that means, though.

Answer (score 1):

I use Go Launcher Pro. There in the running tab it shows Clock. May be he stock launcher application hides running system processes from showing.